# Confirmação para deleção

Tags: php, javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Estou com seguinte problema, estou precisando validar a deleção de um campo, e estou fazendo isto via modal do globo bootstrap. Porem o campo vem de uma tabela e preciso que chegue no modal duas informações, o código do cliente a ser deletado e o tipo deste cliente para deletar no banco de dados.

Ambos estão na mesma página, porem eu dou um include em na pagina que lista em uma tabela todos os clientes.

Como devo fazer para que este código seja enviado para o modal ?

Meus códigos:

Mymodal:

```
                                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Tem certeza que deseja excluir este contato ?</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body" align="center">
                                            <form action="C_DeletaCliente.php" method="get">
                                                <?php
                                                $cdCli = $_GET['P_COD_IDENT_CLIEN'];
                                                $tipo = $_GET['P_FLG_TIPOX_CLIEN'];

                                                echo $cdCli+","+$tipo;
                                                ?>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><a> Sim</a></button>
                                            </form>
                                            <button type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default"><a> Não</a></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Lista Clientes:

```
    // executa  query de consulta e armazena o resultado devolvido na variável $resultado
$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT COD_IDENT_CLIEN, TXT_NOMEX_CLIEN, FLG_TIPOX_CLIEN, FLG_IDENT_STATU from tbl_CLIENTES ORDER BY FLG_TIPOX_CLIEN, TXT_NOMEX_CLIEN ASC");

// se não existir cargos cadastrados exibe uma mensagem
if (mysql_num_rows($resultado) <= 0) {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-error'>";
    echo "<b>Atenção!</b><br>";
    echo "Não existe clientes cadastrados no momento.";
    echo "</div>";
}

// se existir produtos cadastrados lista-os
else {
    echo "<table class='lista-clientes table table-striped'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<th>Nome do Cliente</th>";
    echo "<th>Tipo de Cliente</th>";
    echo "<th>Status do Cliente</th>";
    echo "<th>Excluir</th>";
    echo "<th>Alterar</th>";
    echo "<th>Uploads</th>";
    echo "<th>Agenda</th>";
    echo "<th>Publicações</th>";
    echo "<th>Recados</th>";
    echo "</thead>";

    while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$linha[1]</td>";
        switch ($linha[2]) {
            case 'F':
                echo "<td>Pessoa Fisica</td>";
                break;

            case 'J':
                echo "<td>Pessoa Juridica</td>";
                break;

            default:
                echo "<td>Não cadastrado</td>";
                break;
        }
                switch (@$linha[FLG_IDENT_STATU]) {
            case 'A':
                echo "<td>Ativo</td>";
                break;

            case 'I':
                echo "<td>Inativo</td>";
                break;

            default:
                echo "<td>Não cadastrado</td>";
                break;
        }
        echo "<td><a href='#myModal2?P_COD_IDENT_CLIEN={$linha[0]}&P_FLG_TIPOX_CLIEN={$linha[2]}' data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#myModal2\"><i class='icon-remove' ></i></a></td>";
        switch ($linha[2]) {
            case 'F':
                echo "<td><a href='alteraPF.php?P_COD_IDENT_CLIEN={$linha[0]}'><i class='icon-pencil' ></i></a></td>";
                break;
            case 'J':
                echo "<td><a href='alteraPJ.php?P_COD_IDENT_CLIEN={$linha[0]}'><i class='icon-pencil' ></i></a></td>";
                break;
        }
        echo "<td><a href='uploadCliente.php?P_COD_IDENT_CLIEN={$linha[0]}'><i class='icon-upload-alt' ></i></a></td>";
        echo "<td><a href='agendaCliente.php?P_COD_IDENT_CLIEN={$linha[0]}'><i class='icon-calendar' ></i></a></td>";
        switch ($linha[2]) {
            case 'F':
                echo "<td><a href='publicacaoPF.php?P_COD_IDENT_CLIEN={$linha[0]}'><i class='icon-file' ></i></a></td>";
                break;
            case 'J':
                echo "<td><a href='publicacaoPJ.php?P_COD_IDENT_CLIEN={$linha[0]}'><i class='icon-file' ></i></a></td>";
                break;
        }
        echo "<td><a href='listaRecadosClientes.php?P_COD_IDENT_CLIEN={$linha[0]}'><i class='icon-inbox' ></i></a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
}
```

> O objetivo desta pergunta é tentar fazer algo para validar a deleção do campo, se caso existir alguma maneira mais eficaz, ou mais fácil de se desenvolver aceito indicações.

Comment: Como você chama esse modal? Ele é um arquivo externo ou está na mesma página?

Comment: Ele está na mesma página, e a forma de chama-lo é quando clico no botão X, ele dispara um evento por meio do data-toggle="modal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um plugin como o [Bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html) basta implementa-lo no teu código.

A chamada pode ser feita assim

```
$(document).on('click', '.confirma-delete', function(event){
   // Evento padrão do click
   event.preventDefault();

   // ve se tem titulo
   var title = $(this).data('title');
   var id    = $(this).data('id');
   var tipo  = $(this).data('type');

   var msg = 'Realmente deseja deletar <span class="text-danger">' + title + '</span>?';

   bootbox.confirm(msg, function(res){

     if (res) deletaDados(id, tipo);

   });


});
```

E no teu *loop* faça os links assim:

```
<a 
  href='#myModal2' 
  data-title='{$linha[1]}' 
  data-id='{$linha[0]}'
  data-type='{$linha[2]}' 
  class='confirma-delete'
>
```

#### Exemplo

```js
$(document).on('click', '.confirma-delete', function(event){
   // Evento padrão do click
   event.preventDefault();

   // ve se tem titulo
   var title = $(this).data('title');
   var id    = $(this).data('id');
   var tipo  = $(this).data('type');

   var msg = 'Realmente deseja deletar <span class="text-danger">' + title + '</span>?';

   bootbox.confirm(msg, function(res){

     if (res) {
       // Chama sua função para deletar os dados
       // deletaDados(id, tipo);
       bootbox.alert('Deletado com sucesso!');
     }

   });


});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/releases/download/v4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
      <caption>Optional table caption.</caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
          <td><button class="confirma-delete btn btn-danger" data-title="Mark" data-id="1" data-type="user">x</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
          <td><button class="confirma-delete btn btn-danger" data-title="Jacob" data-id="1" data-type="user">x</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
          <td><button class="confirma-delete btn btn-danger" data-title="Larry" data-id="1" data-type="user">x</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Está faltando chamar o arquivo bootbox não ?

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo ai @RenanRodrigues

Answer (score 1):

Crie dois campos vazios no seu modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<input type="hidden" data-name="mdClientCode">
<input type="hidden" data-name="mdClientType">
```

<sub>Você também pode criar esses campos automaticamente via javascript...</sub>

Crie um arquivo `jquery.functions.js` e coloque a seguinte função nele. O arquivo deve ser incluído no teu código após o jQuery.

```
$.fn.dataByPrefix = function( pr ){
  var d=this.data(), r=new RegExp("^"+pr), ob={};
  for(var k in d) if(r.test(k)) ob[k]=d[k];
  return ob;
};
```

<sub>Função tirada desta [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27973784/3497987)</sub>

Crie uma função de chamada do seu próprio modal:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="meumodal"]', function(event){
   // Evento padrão do click
   event.preventDefault();

   // Seleciona o modal
   var modal = $( $(this).data('target') );

   // Pega os dados que estão no elemento clicado (a[data-toggle="meumodal"])
   var dados = $(this).dataByPrefix("md");

   // Loop nos dados
   for(i in dados){

     var el = modal.find('input[type="hidden"][data-name=" '+i+' "]');

     // Verifica se tem um input do dado dentro do modal
     // Se não tiver cria-o
     if (el.length == 0){
        el = $('<input />').attr('type','hidden')
                           .attr('data-name', 'i');
        modal.append(el);
     }
     // Atribui o valor a ele
     el.val( dados[i] );
   }

   modal.modal('show');
});
```

Construa a chamada da seguinte forma:

```
<a 
  href='#myModal2' 
  data-md-client-code='{$linha[0]}' 
  data-md-client-type='{$linha[2]}' 
  data-toggle='meumodal' 
  data-target='#myModal2'
>
```

Passe os dados usando o prefixo `md` do data, ou seja `data-md-minhakey="meu-valor"`. O prefixo `md` é só uma sugestão, pode usar o prefixo que desejar.

Comment: O meu jquery e via web ? como faço ? e está dando erro justamente nele @KaduAmaral

Comment: crie um arquivo e chame-o depois que linkar o jQuery

Comment: Não está chamando meu modal, o erro o jquery acabou porem não aparece o modal.

Comment: você alterou o data-toggle para 'meumodal', ou qualquer que seja o nome que você tenha dado? Entra nesse chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25038/javascript

Answer (score 0):

Colocando os dados em dois campos hidden acredito que funciona:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cod_cli" value="<?php echo $_GET['P_COD_IDENT_CLIEN']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="tipo_cli" value="<?php echo $_GET['P_FLG_TIPOX_CLIEN']; ?>">
```

Depois é só capturar no PHP pelo método `$_POST`:

```
$codigo_cliente = $_POST['cod_cli'];
$tipo_cliente   = $_POST['tipo_cli'];
```

E apagar o dado:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_CLIENTES 
WHERE  P_FLG_TIPOX_CLIEN='$tipo_cliente'
AND    P_COD_IDENT_CLIEN='$codigo_cliente';
```

> Não esqueça de alterar o `method="get"` para  `method="post"`.

A propósito, existe sim uma maneira melhor de fazer isso, via ajax.

Comment: Não funcionou, ele acusa que a variável não tem valor, na real o erro ta sendo na forma de envio, não estou sabendo enviar a informação para o modal..

Comment: Eu so preciso enviar os dados par ao modal, o restante está funcionando perfeitamente, o problema está ao enviar o dados para o modal que se encontra na mesma página, reveja seu código pois isso não está fazendo o que soluciona o meu problema.

Comment: você não captura método post se enviá-lo via get.